# Sudoku program failing to compile

Tags: java

I am working on to build a Sudoku programm. when i compile, i have many errors but i can't see the actual what error were they.

```
   if (b == true);
    ^
bchimedochir_Sudoku1.java:184: error: <identifier> expected
    if (b == true);
         ^
bchimedochir_Sudoku1.java:184: error: ';' expected
    if (b == true);
            ^
bchimedochir_Sudoku1.java:184: error: illegal start of type
    if (b == true);
                 ^
bchimedochir_Sudoku1.java:184: error: <identifier> expected
    if (b == true);
                  ^
bchimedochir_Sudoku1.java:184: error: ';' expected
    if (b == true);
                   ^
bchimedochir_Sudoku1.java:186: error: illegal start of type
    System.out.println("Congratulation !\n");
          ^
bchimedochir_Sudoku1.java:186: error: ';' expected
    System.out.println("Congratulation !\n");
              ^
bchimedochir_Sudoku1.java:186: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
    System.out.println("Congratulation !\n");
               ^
bchimedochir_Sudoku1.java:186: error: illegal start of type
    System.out.println("Congratulation !\n");
                       ^
bchimedochir_Sudoku1.java:187: error: <identifier> expected
    System.out.println("This Sudoku is valid.\n");
                      ^
bchimedochir_Sudoku1.java:187: error: illegal start of type
    System.out.println("This Sudoku is valid.\n");
                       ^
bchimedochir_Sudoku1.java:188: error: illegal start of type
    else
    ^
bchimedochir_Sudoku1.java:188: error: ';' expected
    else
        ^
bchimedochir_Sudoku1.java:190: error: illegal start of type
        System.out.println("Sorry !\n");
              ^
bchimedochir_Sudoku1.java:190: error: ';' expected
        System.out.println("Sorry !\n");
                  ^
bchimedochir_Sudoku1.java:190: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
        System.out.println("Sorry !\n");
                   ^
bchimedochir_Sudoku1.java:190: error: illegal start of type
        System.out.println("Sorry !\n");
                           ^
bchimedochir_Sudoku1.java:191: error: <identifier> expected
    System.out.println("This Sudoku is invalid.\n");
                      ^
bchimedochir_Sudoku1.java:191: error: illegal start of type
    System.out.println("This Sudoku is invalid.\n");
                       ^
20 errors
bchimedochir@loki:~/F12_1400-005_prog7$ vim bchimedochir_Sudoku1.java
bchimedochir@loki:~/F12_1400-005_prog7$ javac bchimedochir_Sudoku1.java
bchimedochir_Sudoku1.java:184: error: illegal start of type
    if (b == true);
    ^
bchimedochir_Sudoku1.java:184: error: <identifier> expected
    if (b == true);
         ^
bchimedochir_Sudoku1.java:184: error: ';' expected
    if (b == true);
            ^
bchimedochir_Sudoku1.java:184: error: illegal start of type
    if (b == true);
                 ^
bchimedochir_Sudoku1.java:184: error: <identifier> expected
    if (b == true);
                  ^
bchimedochir_Sudoku1.java:184: error: ';' expected
    if (b == true);
                   ^
bchimedochir_Sudoku1.java:185: error: illegal start of type
    System.out.print("Congratulation !\n");
          ^
bchimedochir_Sudoku1.java:185: error: ';' expected
    System.out.print("Congratulation !\n");
              ^
bchimedochir_Sudoku1.java:185: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
    System.out.print("Congratulation !\n");
               ^
bchimedochir_Sudoku1.java:185: error: illegal start of type
    System.out.print("Congratulation !\n");
                     ^
bchimedochir_Sudoku1.java:186: error: <identifier> expected
    System.out.print("This Sudoku is valid.\n");
                    ^
bchimedochir_Sudoku1.java:186: error: illegal start of type
    System.out.print("This Sudoku is valid.\n");
                     ^
bchimedochir_Sudoku1.java:187: error: illegal start of type
    else
    ^
bchimedochir_Sudoku1.java:187: error: ';' expected
    else
        ^
bchimedochir_Sudoku1.java:188: error: illegal start of type
        System.out.print("Sorry !\n");
              ^
bchimedochir_Sudoku1.java:188: error: ';' expected
        System.out.print("Sorry !\n");
                  ^
bchimedochir_Sudoku1.java:188: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
        System.out.print("Sorry !\n");
                   ^
bchimedochir_Sudoku1.java:188: error: illegal start of type
        System.out.print("Sorry !\n");
                         ^
bchimedochir_Sudoku1.java:189: error: <identifier> expected
    System.out.print("This Sudoku is invalid.\n");
                    ^
bchimedochir_Sudoku1.java:189: error: illegal start of type
    System.out.print("This Sudoku is invalid.\n");
```

Here is my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class bchimedochir_Sudoku 
{
public static void main(String args[])

    {   
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int r1c1;
    int r1c2;
    int r1c3;
    int r1c4;
    int r2c1;
    int r2c2;
    int r2c3;
    int r2c4;
    int r3c1;
    int r3c2;
    int r3c3;
    int r3c4;
    int r4c1;
    int r4c2;
    int r4c3;
    int r4c4;
    int total;
    boolean b = true;


        System.out.printf("Welcome to Sudoku Checker v1.0!\n");
        System.out.printf("This program checks simple, small, 4X4 Sudoku grids for\n");
        System.out.printf("correctness. Each column, row and 2X2 region contains the numbers\n");
        System.out.printf("1 through 4 only once.\n\n");
        System.out.printf("To check your Sudoku, enter your board one row at a time, with\n");
        System.out.printf("Each digit separated by a space. Hit enter at the end of the row.\n\n");

        System.out.print("Enter Row 1 :");
        r1c1 = input.nextInt();
        r1c2 = input.nextInt();
        r1c3 = input.nextInt();
        r1c4 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter Row 2 :");
        r2c1 = input.nextInt();
        r2c2 = input.nextInt();
        r2c3 = input.nextInt();
        r2c4 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter Row 3 :");
        r3c1 = input.nextInt();
        r3c2 = input.nextInt();
        r3c3 = input.nextInt();
        r3c4 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter Row 4 :");
        r4c1 = input.nextInt();
        r4c2 = input.nextInt();
        r4c3 = input.nextInt();
        r4c4 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Thank you. Now Checking ...\n\n");

        sum = r1c1 + r1c2 + r1c3 + r1c4;
        if (total == sum) 
        {
          System.out.print("ROW-1:PASS\n");
        } else 
        {
            b = false;
            System.out.print("ROW-1:FAILED\n");
        }

        sum = r2c1 + r2c2 + r2c3 + r2c4;
        if (total == sum) 
        {
            System.out.print("ROW-2:PASS\n");
        } else 
        {
            b = false;
            System.out.print("ROW-2:FAILED\n");
        }

        sum = r3c1 + r3c2 + r3c3 + r3c4;
        if (total == sum) 
        {
            System.out.print("ROW-3:PASS\n");
        } else 
        {
            b = false;
            System.out.print("ROW-3:FAILED\n");
        }

        sum = r4c1 + r4c2 + r4c3 + r4c4;
        if (total == sum) 
        {
            System.out.print("ROW-4:PASS\n");
        } else 
        {
            b = false;
            System.out.print("ROW-4:FAILED\n");
        }

        sum = r1c1 + r2c1 + r3c1 + r4c1;
        if (total == sum) 
        {
            System.out.print("COL-1:PASS\n");
        } else 
        {
            b = false;
            System.out.print("COL-1:FAILED\n");
        }

        sum = r1c2 + r2c2 + r3c2 + r4c2;
        if (total == sum) 
        {
            System.out.print("COL-2:PASS\n");
        } else 
        {
            b = false;
            System.out.print("COL-2:FAILED\n");
        }

        sum = r1c3 + r2c3 + r3c3 + r4c3;
        if (total == sum) 
        {
            System.out.print("COL-3:PASS\n");
        } else 
        {
            b = false;
            System.out.print("COL-3:FAILED\n");
        }

        sum = r1c4 + r2c4 + r3c4 + r4c4;
        if (total == sum) 
        {
            System.out.print("COL-4:PASS\n");
        } else 
        {
            b = false;
            System.out.print("COL-4:FAILED\n");
        }

        sum = r1c1 + r1c2 + r2c1 + r2c2;
        if (total == sum) 
        {
            System.out.print("REG-1:PASS\n");
        } else 
        {
            b = false;
            System.out.print("REG-1:FAILED\n");
        }

        sum = r3c1 + r3c2 + r4c1 + r4c2;
        if (total == sum) 
        {
            System.out.print("REG-2:PASS\n");
        } else 
        {
            b = false;
            System.out.print("REG-2:FAILED\n");
        }

        sum = r1c3 + r1c4 + r2c3 + r2c4;
        if (total == sum) 
        {
            System.out.print("REG-3:PASS\n");
        } else 
        {
            b = false;
            System.out.printf("REG-3:PASS %d\n",sum);
            System.out.print("REG-3:FAILED\n");
        }

        sum = r3c3 + r3c4 + r4c3 + r4c4;
        if (total == sum) 
        {
            System.out.print("REG-4:PASS\n");
        } else 
        {
            b = false;
            System.out.print("REG-4:FAILED\n");
        }
    }
       if (b == true); 

            System.out.println("Congratulation !\n");
            System.out.println("This Sudoku is valid.\n");
         else 

            System.out.println("Sorry !\n");
            System.out.println("This Sudoku is invalid.\n");
}
```

Comment: Please put some effort into your questions.

Comment: *"when i compile, i have many errors"* Write small chinks of code, compile often.

Answer (score 7):

All of this section is broken:

```
if (b == true); 

    System.out.println("Congratulation !\n");
    System.out.println("This Sudoku is valid.\n");
 else 

    System.out.println("Sorry !\n");
    System.out.println("This Sudoku is invalid.\n");
```

It's broken in three ways:

- It all comes *outside the `main` method, because you've got an extra closing brace before it
- It has a semi-colon at the end of the `if` statement, which is equivalent to `{}` in this case
- Your two sets of statements aren't "braced" like the rest of your code

Additionally, comparing with `true` explicitly is ugly, and the variable name `b` is pretty meaningless - and it's at the end of a *massively* overlong method. However, to make it *compile* you probably just need to move the closing brace before this section to after it, and change the section to:

```
if (b)
{
    System.out.println("Congratulation !\n");
    System.out.println("This Sudoku is valid.\n");
}
else 
{
    System.out.println("Sorry !\n");
    System.out.println("This Sudoku is invalid.\n");
}
```

... but don't just fix that. Revisit your whole design. No-one wants to read a 188-line method. You should also consider using arrays instead of having 16 separate variables...

Comment: Thanks I fixed but it says :189: error: 'else' without 'if'
        } else
          ^
1 error

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're closing your `main` method prematurely: look at the first line that the compiler complains about: `if (b == true)`. The closing brace before that line is closing your `main` method, leaving the rest of the code as bare code in the class, i.e. *outside* a method, which isn't allowed.

The same line is prematurely terminated by a semicolon:

```
if (b == true); // <- remove the semicolon
```

And the same `if/else` statement needs some compound statement blocks:

```
if (b == true)
{  // add the block
   System.out.println("Congratulation !\n");
   System.out.println("This Sudoku is valid.\n");
}
else 
{  // ditto here
   System.out.println("Sorry !\n");
   System.out.println("This Sudoku is invalid.\n");
}
```

Finally, you don't need to compare against `true` and `false`: `if (b)` is fine for this test; `if (b == true)` will still work, but it's redundant.

Comment: likewise your if (b == true) is terminated by the semi-colon, so the following *else* is orphaned, and all the printf statements will be executed (valid and invalid) once you apply the above fix

Comment: You've still got the semi-colon in your "fixed" code...